# I seem to be sending like requests for a page, but I don't see that in my activity log

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

So I'm apparently sending like requests for a certain Facebook page to my Facebook friends. I can't figure out how that is happening and I can't see any activity about that in my activity log.

I've changed my password, removed all authorized applications (nothing strange there, but I don't really use any of them anyway), ended all other sessions (nothing strange there as well!).

So my question is: Is there any way to actually see to whom did I send those like requests?

Comment: By _sending like requests for Facebook page to my Facebook friends_ you mean inviting friends to like that Facebook page?

Comment: @serenesat Yes, that seems to be the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Inviting friends to like a page will not show in activity log.

If you want to see whom you have invited:

Go to your page, hover over the cursor on **...More** tab, from the drop down menu, click on **Invite Friends**. A window will popup which show you all your friends who have liked the page, who have been invited to like the page and whom you can invite.

On the popup window if you choose the option *Selected*, it will list all the friends who have been invited but not liked the page.

*Note: This answer only will work when your are admin of the page.*

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not the admin of the page.

Comment: Then _Invite Friends_ under _...More_ will not be visible to you.